# What is the area of $y^2=\sqrt x-x$ (Guitar Pick)

Tags: calculus, integration

I made a typo while experimenting on Desmos and typed $y^2=\sqrt x-x$. It drew a shape, one that I've never seen before:
[image] With my very limited knowledge of calculus, I know the area would be equal to: $$2\int_0^1 \sqrt{\sqrt x - x} \,dx$$ However, I have no clue how to evaluate this integral. Using Desmos, I can get a decimal approximation (it's about 0.785), and Wolfram Alpha can give me the final result ($\pi/4$). No site I can think of has the solution and steps to solve it, so I figured I'd ask it here. How would you evaluate this integral?

Comment: You don’t want to tell us what Wolfram Alpha gave you?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews presumably [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+2*sqrt%28sqrt%28x%29-x%29+from+0+to+1)

Comment: I would, but it would take ages to type out the full answer. Here's the link to the calculation, though: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=2Integrate%5BSqrt%5BSqrt%5Bx%5D-x%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D

Comment: The integral is elementary with an area of $\frac\pi 4$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand how you got that. Can you explain in an answer?

Comment: @AaronNight not sure why your link doesn’t give the closed form that Henry got, $\frac\pi4.$

Comment: I don't have Wolfram Alpha Pro, so it refuses to show the full process of solving it. :L

Comment: You can check the full solution using "step by step" on Wolfram Alpha for free. Just re-ask to Wolfram the result of the first step on "step by step" 's answer. You're welcome

Comment: I've posted a solution for the integral. Check it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start by substituting $x=t^2$. This gives
$$\begin{align}2\int_0^1\sqrt{\sqrt{x}-x}\,\mathrm dx &= 4 \int_0^1 t\sqrt{t-t^2}\,\mathrm dt \\ &= 4 \int_0^1 t\sqrt{\frac14-\Big(t-\frac12\Big)^2}\,\mathrm dt \\ &\overset{t-\frac12=u}{=} 4 \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \Big(u+\frac12\Big)\sqrt{\frac14-u^2}\,\mathrm du \\ &= 4 \int_0^{1/2} \sqrt{\frac14-u^2} \,\mathrm du \quad \text{ odd and even integrand} \\ &= \left. 2u\sqrt{\frac14-u^2}+\frac12 \arcsin\Big(\frac u{1/2}\Big) \right|_0^{1/2}\\ &= \frac \pi4\end{align}$$
In the last step, I used the formula
$$\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\, dx = \frac x2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}2\arcsin \frac xa+C$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood all of that besides the odd and even integrand part! (doing outside research for that, don't worry about helping with that) Most of my troubles came from the first substitution when doing it before asking this question, though it seems silly to mess up on that now.

Comment: I don't know if you found anything good about the odd even part, so here it is. Consider a function $f(x)$ continuous inside $(-a,a)$, or at most having one jump discontinuity at $x=0$. If $f(-x)=f(x)$ $\forall x\in \mathbb R$. , then the function is called even and $$ \int_{-a}^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx=2 \int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx $$. If $f(-x)=-f(x)$, then the function is called odd and $$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx = 0$$. @Aaron